# apache arrow c++ ParquetFileWriter problem with footer and close

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I tried to have my program write out a stream of data in parquet format via apache arrow's StreamWriter. But the output file do not have the metadata footer. When trying to read in the parquet using python pandas, I get the following error:

`Invalid: Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.`

This [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14066) in arrow seems to provide the solution. Stating that the `ParquetFileWriter` within the `StreamWriter` must be closed to write the footer. (The ticket recommended calling `Close()` indirectly by calling `StreamWriter`'s destructor. But I consistently get a segmentation fault from `ParquetFileWriter.Close()`.

Below is how I have the Writers setup:

```
std::shared_ptr<::arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile_{""};
std::string outputFilePath_ = "/tmp/part.0.parquet";
PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(
    outfile_,
    ::arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(outputFilePath_)
)
// build column names
parquet::schema::NodeVector columnNames_{};
columnNames_.push_back(
    parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make(
        "Time", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, parquet::Type::INT64, parquet::ConvertedType::UINT_64
    )
);
columnNames_.push_back(
    parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make(
        "Value", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, parquet::Type::INT64, parquet::ConvertedType::UINT_64
    )
);
auto schema = std::static_pointer_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode>(
    parquet::schema::GroupNode::Make("schema", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, columnNames_)
);
parquet::WriterProperties::Builder builder;
std::unique_ptr<parquet::ParquetFileWriter> fwriter = parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(outfile_, schema, builder.build())
parquet::StreamWriter os_ = parquet::StreamWriter {std::move(fwriter)};

// Start writing to os_, would be in a callback function
os_ << std::uint64_t{5} << std::uint64_t{59};
os_.EndRow();
os_.EndRowGroup();
```

I have tried the following methods but they all yield a seg fault:
`os_.~StreamWriter();`
OR
`fwriter.Close()`

Comment: Could this be caused by an uncaught exception on fwriter.Close()?

Comment: should I be expecting an exception?

Comment: Closing the filewriter is what actually writes the footer so it can throw an exception.  I would expect fwriter.Close() to segfault since it is no longer valid after the move to construct the stream writer.  Also, be careful with callback functions, the writer is not thread-safe as far as I remember.

Comment: Even if i call os_.~StreamWriter(), I will encounter the same problem. The non-thread-safe issue might be the source of this. Still exploring solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I had the same problem with yours. After carefully comparing the code of yours (as well as mine) and the [code on JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/13034024/temp.cpp), the difference is that `builder` is a `shared_pointer`. Therefore, by changing the `shared_pointer` to a normal `parquet::WriterProperties::Builder builder;` and later using `builder.build()`, things should then work out fine.